# Find DNA nucleotides anywhere is line

Tags: perl

I'm writing a perl script and I need to find letters of DNA (a,g,t,c) anywhere on the line.
So far I have

```
while (FILE)
{ if ($_ =~ /[A+][G+][T+][C+]/)
print "this is valid";
}
```

I know this part needs to be fixed but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Appreciate your time

Comment: Assuming ATCG can appear at any order, seems your check should be

if($_ =~ m/[AGTC]+/)
{
print "...";
}

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your script. That will help you find multiple issues.

Comment: I don't see the point in downvoting a biologist's Perl question.

Comment: Thanks Sayutee! It works! Yes I have the rest of it, I just didn't put it on here.

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks.

- You've hopefully opened the FILE handle.
- You should read the FILE handle line by line with the `<>` operator.
- The `if ()` must be followed by a block, not a single statement.
- You can omit `$_ =~`, it's implied automatically when matching a pattern.
- It seems that a single instance of one of the four letters is enough, see the regexp.
- Note my indentation style, this is the official Perl style.

Code:

```
open FILE, "filename" or die;
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/[AGTC]/) {
        print "this is valid";
    }
}
```

There is a shorter form of `if` for single statements. You can omit both the parens around the condition and the block.

```
open FILE, "filename" or die;
while (<FILE>) {
    print "this is valid" if /[AGTC]/;
}
```